# Link inside link

Tags: html, css

If I have code like this, how can I make link from `.layer` or `.layer-info`? I prefer solution without JavaScript but I will be happy for any kind of solution.

```
<div class="layer">
  <img src="http://besttours.com/media/catalog/category/NYC_2-compressor.jpg" alt="">
  <div class="layer-info">
    <h5>NYC</h5>
    <p class="small">USA</p>
    <ul class="absolute-bottom">
      <li><a href="">Hotels</a></li>
      <li><a href="">What to do</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Tickets</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Working example is here : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VaEPdy

Comment: I don't think there's any other way, unless you are using positioning.

Comment: You don't. Link the image or the `h5`

Comment: Found the solution and it works as well.

Comment: @KarolinaTicha Can you kindly confirm if the solution you are looking for matches what I have provided?

Comment: Link to what?  Any link wrapper or overlay will disable the links inside/underneath. it's not clear what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `position`ing to achieve it. There are side-effects as well. Add an `absolute`ly positioned `<a>` inside the layer, which is already relative.

This way, there are few things:

- You have the whole layer in a clickable link.
- The inner links, the textual links are still functional.
- No JavaScript.
- Kind of links, inside a link is achieved.
- Semantically valid.

```css
img {
  width: 100%;
}
.layer {
  position: relative;
}
.layer-info {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.biglink {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; bottom: 0;
  left: 0; right: 0;
  display: block;
  z-index: 999;
}
.absolute-bottom a {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1000;
}
```

```html
<div class="layer">
  <a href="http://google.com" class="biglink"></a>
  <img src="http://besttours.com/media/catalog/category/NYC_2-compressor.jpg" alt="">
  <div class="layer-info">
    <h5>NYC</h5>
    <p class="small">USA</p>
    <ul class="absolute-bottom">
      <li><a href="">Hotels</a></li>
      <li><a href="">What to do</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Tickets</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

The `<a>` (big link) is positioned with `z-index` of `999`, while the three links, inside the content are positioned `relative` with `z-index` of `1000` making both working and semantically correct as well.